# git restrict "add" and "commit" from subdirectory of repository

Tags: git

Is there any way to restrict git `add` and `commit` if you are not in root directory of git repository (where .git is located)?

I am asking because my `$HOME` directory is under git control and sometimes I'm adding and committing something occasionally. It is happens when I forget to init new repo.

Here is short description of what I want:

```
mkdir /tmp/git_test && cd /tmp/git_test && touch t1 t2 t3
git init && git add -A && git commit -m "INIT" 
touch t4 t5 t6 # create new files
mkdir /tmp/git_test/git_test2 && cd /tmp/git_test/git_test2
git add -A # on this step it should not allow me to add files t4 t5 and t6 because I'm in subdirectory
```

On this last step, I want to get some yes/no dialog, or just error. But in fact it allows to add files.

```
(/tmp/git_test/git_test2)$ git status -sb
## master
A  ../t4
A  ../t5
A  ../t6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git always walks up parent directories looking for the first `.git/` it finds, so there's no built-in way to do this.

But, you could add a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) that checks for a `.git/` in your current directory and halts the commit if it's not there.

Even if you've accidentally staged or committed files to a repository you didn't mean to, you can undo it with [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using hooks, I was thinking about workaround using bash aliases